# What kind of curve is this, from the distribution of roots of Catalan polynomials?

Tags: co.combinatorics

We consider the distribution of roots of some Catalan polynomials.
And we get the following curve that the roots approach it.
What kind of curve is this?

[image: Distribution of roots of Catalan polynomials]

Comment: How are you defining Catalan polynomials?

Comment: With more details this could be an interesting question. I wouldn't want to see it closed.

Comment: Hi L. Mu welcome to MO. Thanks for posting this question. However, some MO users have flagged your question as "unclear what you're asking." Could you define Catalan polynomials and be specific about how you are choosing "some" in your "roots of some Catalan polynomials"? Setting your notation and normalization (if any) will hopefully lead to a more relevant answer. If the question does get closed, it would likely be a good candidate for re-opening after those questions are addressed.